# how to set values of radiobutton groups in angular ngfor

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a graph using radiobuttons but i have some problems inserting array-values in the ngfor loop. idealy it should look like this [radiobutton graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/un6AF.jpg)

```
        <tr *ngFor="let graph of graphitems[0][0].questions; let i = index" id="quesfor">
          <th>{{graph}}</th>
          <th>
            <div *ngFor="let answer of graphitems[0][i].answers; let j = index" id="graphradio">
              <input type="radio" id="one" name="{{j}}">
              <input type="radio" id="one" name="{{j}}">
              <input type="radio" id="one" name="{{j}}">
              <input type="radio" id="one" name="{{j}}">
              <input type="radio" id="one" name="{{j}}">
              <p>{{answer}}</p>
            </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work? (this assumes that answer is a number and not a string.)

```
<tr *ngFor="let graph of graphitems[0][0].questions; let i = index" id="quesfor">
      <th>{{graph}}</th>
      <th>
        <div *ngFor="let answer of graphitems[0][i].answers; let j = index" id="graphradio">
          <input type="radio" id="one" name="{{j}}" [checked]="answer === 5">
          <input type="radio" id="one" name="{{j}}" [checked]="answer === 4">
          <input type="radio" id="one" name="{{j}}" [checked]="answer === 3">
          <input type="radio" id="one" name="{{j}}" [checked]="answer === 2">
          <input type="radio" id="one" name="{{j}}" [checked]="answer === 1">
          <p>{{answer}}</p>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
```

Comment: answer is indeed a number

Comment: If this is working for you, please accept my answer